# With or without a preposition?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Certainly, it is not as easy to learn to read and spell English **as it
>   is most other** phonetic languages.

from *Uncovering the Logic of English: A Common-Sense Approach to Reading, Spelling, and Literacy*

Shouldn't it have been *"as it is **in** most other phonetic languages"* or *"as it is **with** most other phonetic languages"*? Or the presented wording is acceptable too?

Comment: Maybe, *"Certainly, it is not as easy to learn to read and spell English as it is (to learn to read and spell) most other phonetic languages."* I might be wrong, I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

> Certainly, it is not as easy to learn to read and spell English as it is most other phonetic languages.

Similar to what user dan says in [a comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221562/with-or-without-a-preposition#comment423273_221562), the above sentence expands into the following:

> Certainly, it is not as easy to learn to read and spell English as it is [**easy to learn to read and spell**] most other phonetic languages.

---

Your suggestion, *as it is **in** most other phonetic languages* would work had the sentence read as follows:

> Certainly, it is not as easy to learn to read and spell **in** English as it is most other phonetic languages.

However, that's not the intended meaning, so that suggestion doesn't quite work.

Comment: I dunno, it just sounds weird to me. I agree that it might be what the phrase is trying to convey, but Google gives a lopsided victory to **as it is in\with most other** against **as it is most other**. I might think that only the **it is not as easy** part is meant: _Certainly, **it is not as easy** to do X as it is (**in**) most other languages._

Comment: @MichaelLogin It's not weird at all. You have to expose yourself to English some more, I suppose. As I said in my comment to the other answer, examining the frequency of each expression is the wrong path to take in this case, and the results you think you've gotten are misleading. It's unclear to me what you meant by *I might think that only...*. A simplified example (similar to those in the other answer) might be *It's not as easy to learn English **as it is** French*, or *It's not as easy to learn to read **in** English **as it is in** French*. But you can't combine the two.